# Gradle productFlavors not creating package

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In `.gradle` file I wrote `productFlavors` block but it didn't create `free` and `pro` packages.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know where is the problem :C

I'm using `Android Studio 1.5.1` and `gradle 1.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) says, you need to create them manually (look at the point 2):

> To create different product versions of your app:
>
> 1. Define product flavors in the build file.
> 2. Create additional source directories for each flavor.
> 3. Add the flavor-specific sources to your project.

Comment: From documantation: `5. Right click on the java directory under app/src/demo and select New > Package.` But There is no `New->Package`. Android studio sees `pro/java` as folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are trying to create the package in your already selected variant/flavor/config.